# Can I inject multiple spring dependencies from struts actions

Tags: spring, struts2

I have struts xml in which I had created one action say Baseaction. I need to inject all the beans defined in application context file.

I am using struts2 spring plug-in. Can I inject all the bean dependencies from springs application context xml file separately.

Thanks,
Nilesh

Comment: What do you mean by *Can I inject all the bean dependencies from springs application context xml file separately* ?

Comment: Apologies Garry, I have not much described the problem. Actually problem is I want to inject dependency in struts framework application. I am able to inject the same in struts action class. But the problem is I want to insert (Dao dependency) dependencies in other classes like serviceImpl classes, so can I inject them without defining multiple struts actions in struts.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Set Spring as Struts objectFactory in **Struts.xml**:

```xml
<struts>
  <constant name="struts.objectFactory" value="spring" />
  ...
</struts>
```

Declare the Spring listener in **web.xml**:

```xml
<listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

Since the default autowire strategy is by name, just provide an Action property with a setter for each bean you want to be injected in that Action.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" 
                       "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans default-autowire="autodetect">
    <bean id="fooManager" class="com.acme.FooManager" 
       scope="prototype"/>
    ...
</beans>
```

Read more on the [documentation](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/spring-plugin.html).

If you need to inject **all** your beans in an action, then declare **all** the corrispondent properties and setters in that action.

This btw is weird, because if the BaseAction will be extended by all other actions, it is unlikely that each one of the other actions will need **all** the beans... you should define the beans in the actions that need them; this sounds like a bit of lazyness, that will cost your webapp a bit of performance.

Comment: Thanks Andrea, Actually I am able to inject multiple bean dependencies in struts action class. My problem is I want to inject dependencies in another class. Means suppose I have BaseAction class as a struts action class and I am calling BaseService class method from that. After that I am calling say LoginService class method from BaseService class.

Comment: Now here the problem is exist. I have one Dao lets say UserDAO class, and I want to inject Dao class dependency in LoginService class. When I put getter, setter for UserDAO and accessing the same then I am getting null in UserDAO object.(NullPointerException). So can I load dependencies in such classes without struts action?